# Java program is getting slower after running for a while

Tags: java, linux, performance, memory, garbage-collection

I have a java program that is a typical machine learning algorithm, updating the values for some parameters by some equations:

```
for (int iter=0; iter<1000; iter++) {
    // 1. Create many temporary variables and do some computations                         
    // 2. Update the value for the parameters                    
}
```

The computations of updating parameters are rather complex, and I have to create many temporary objects, but they are not referenced out of the loop. The code in the loop is CPU-intensive, and does not access disk. This program loads a relatively large training dataset, therefore, I granted 10G memory (-Xmx10G) to JVM, which is much larger than it requires (peak at ~6G by "top" command or window's task manager).

I tested it on several linux machines (centos 6, 24G memory) and a window machine (win7, 12G), both with SUN Hotspot JDK/JRE 1.8 installed. I did not specify other JVM parameters except -Xmx. Both machines are dedicated to my program.

On windows, my program runs well: each iteration uses very similar running time. However, the running time on all of the centos machines is weird.
**It initially runs properly, but slows down dramatically (~10 times slower) at 7th/8th iteration, and then keeps slow down ~10% in each iteration ever after.**

I suspect it might be caused by Java's garbage collector. Therefore, I use jconsole to monitor my program. Minor GC happens very frequently on both machines , that is because the program creates many temporary variable in the loop. Furthermore, I used "jstat -gcutil $pid$ 1s" command and captured the statistics:

Centos: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioz7ai6i1h57eoo/jstat.png?dl=0

Window: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uxb7ltbx9kpm9l/jstat-winpng.png?dl=0

[Edited] However, the statistics on two kinds of machines differ a lot:

1. "S1” on windows jumps fast between 0 to 50, while stays at "0.00" on centos.
2. "E" on windows changes very rapidly from 0 to 100. As I print the stat for every second, the screenshot does not show its increment to 100. On centos, however, "E" increases rather slowly towards 100, and then reduces to 0, and increases again.

**It seems the weird behaviour of my program is due to Java GC?** I am  new to Java performance monitor and do not have a good idea to optimize GC parameter setting. Do you have any suggestions?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you have to create a lot of "temporary" objects inside the loop? If you could pull some of them out of the loop and re-use the same instances in each iteration, it would save some to a lot of garbage (collection),

Comment: I could not move them out of the loop. The reason is they are used to store the temporary values for the complex mathematical computation.

Comment: If you're not using immutable objects, you can usually just change the values stored inside them (`setX(...)`,...) without creating a new object.

Comment: Is the jstat output from when you actually run the program under load? It seems the application is quite inactive while you run jstat. If that is the output you get under load your GC pauses are insignificant and you should look elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: How much physical memory do you have on the respective machines? It could be a case of too little physical memory on the centOS machines compared to the Windows machine and when the heap grows you get swapping of the heap.

Comment: note: comparing GC performance across different operating systems is not a good idea. Each JVM implementation will be different.

Comment: @Kristoffer E: Yes, the jstat is from when the program is actually running.  Windows  has 12G and  centos has 24G. Both of them are dedicated to my program.

Comment: for centos, which jdk are you using?

Comment: @I.K. It's Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17), and my windows machine uses  1.8.0_25-b18

Comment: @TaoChen then I think the GC is not the culprit here. You have very low pauses during the timespan jstat runs. We need more information. What do your application actually do? Is it CPU bound or is there IO involved? Does it run multi threaded? How long is a typical run? How does things like CPU usage, disk usage and physical memory usage look when the application runs on the CentOS machines? Also, some thread dumps taken from when the application has slowed down is useful. Run jstack <pid> for like 10 times with some seconds inbetween.

Comment: @KristofferE  It is CPU-intensive (almost use 100% of CPU), and does not access disk.   I have used "ps" to monitor the memory usage for the server, it is very stable, and the machine does not have any other heavy job. At the beginning, each iteration takes around 400s, and then jumps to 2950s at  8th iteration, and increases the execution time by 10%  in each later iteration.  I have observed the first big jump almost happened at 7th or 8th iteration.

Comment: are you able to experiment with HotSpot to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: @KristofferE Here are the output from jstack, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xadbsngserkuozr/AACAq_1Iv1wrpUkWkFIEg5tMa?dl=0

Comment: @I.K. What I am currently using is "Hotspot" Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode). Should I try OpenJDK?

Comment: Yes. I'm just wondering whether it is the specific JVM implementation you are using at the moment which is causing the problem. Please try OpenJDK. It's very difficult to analyse your problem online so I'm just throwing these options at you.

Comment: @TaoChen As can be seen in the thread dumps your app spends a lot of time on lines 143, 267 and 140 in RelevanceModel.java. It would be interesting to see what happens on those lines. Also I see that you use two application threads which open up for concurrency issues. At this point I think we need to see some of your code to be able to help.

Comment: @KristofferE Thanks for your analysis! Here is the code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xhzxg22lz8hdl25/AACBNSg3sLrM-BZad0hv6FFba?dl=0.  Yes, the three lines are expected to take a lot of time since they are either computing the average value for a lot of vectors (line 140 and 143), or looping and doing complex computation (line 267). I also run the program with one thread, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @TaoChen Took a brief look at the code. Unfortunately it is hard to draw any conclusions. As you say it seems to be very CPU bound, why you shouldn't see this behavior if the GC behaves OK, as it seems to do. One thing to investigate is CPU cache hit/misses. Those can affect performance greately and the behavior could vary between platforms. I think you will need to narrow down the problem more for us to be able to help more than this remotely.

Comment: Did it change with a different JVM? Is there the ability to get the source code as complete project (e.g., maven project from github) and to get it running ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to post this as an answer but I don't have enough score to comment.

If you think it's a GC related issue I'd change it for the Garbage 1 Collector –XX:+UseG1GC

I found this brief explanation about it:
http://blog.takipi.com/garbage-collectors-serial-vs-parallel-vs-cms-vs-the-g1-and-whats-new-in-java-8/

Can you run your software under profiling? Try to use the jprofiler, VisualVM or even the netbeans profiler. It may help you a lot.

I noticed that you have your own encapsulation of a vector and matrix. *Maybe* your are spending a lot more memory than necessary with that too. But I don't think that is the problem.

Sorry again about not contributing as a comment. (It would be more appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider declaring the vars outside the loop so mem allocation is done once and eliminate GC completely.

Comment: (including all/any temp vars you need)

Answer (score 1):

Giving Java (or any garbage collecting language) too much memory has an adverse effect on performance. The live (referenced) objects become increasing sparse in memory resulting in more frequent fetches from main memory. Note that in the examples you've shown us the faster windows is doing more quick *and* full GC than Linux - but GC cycles (especially full gcs) are usually bad for performance.

If running the training set does not take an exceptionally long time, then try benchmarking at different memory allocations.

A more radical solution, but one which should have a big impact is to eliminate (or reduce as much as possible) object creation within the loop by recycling objects in pools.

Comment: This sounds like a good lead, especially since there's a sudden large jump in execution time at one point: that sounds like blowing through a cache size limit for your hot data, so you can't keep a whole working set in cache. Maybe a system profiler would be able to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a common best practice to declare Variables outside of loops to avoid garbace collection.
as 'Wagner Tsuchiya' said, try running a profiler if you have doubts about the GC.
If you want some tips on GC tuning, i found nice [blogpost](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/textyle/428187).

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling System.gc() every couple iterations to see if performance goes up or down. This may help you narrow it down to some of the previous answers diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

If the GC time is hundreds of milliseconds as shown in your screenshot then GC is likely not the issue here. I suggest you look into lock contention and possibly IO using a profiler (Netbeans is great). I know you stated your program did very little IO but with profiling (much like debugging) you have to remove all your assumptions and go step by step.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience JAVA needs enough memory and 2+ CPU. Otherwise CPU usage will be very extensive when GC starts running.