# Processing time become slower after several runs

Tags: java, performance, netbeans, nlp, windows-10

In my Java project there are large amount of documents processed in field of NLP, one by one.

In the first run (first document), the processing speed is good, but after several runs the processing speed become slower and slower. I have read on an article that i have to use: System.gc(); , to flush cache !, and it improves the speed a little bit, by it stay slower than first run. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the file access getting slower or the actual computation?

Comment: actual computation.

Comment: this smells like a memory leak, does your memory footprint increase?
Is the problem resolved if you close the JVM and start anew?

Comment: @gismo , yes after closing it become faster, but what you meant by memory footprint ?

Comment: You can watch the behavior of the Garbage Collector (if you're on Linux) with `jstat -gcutil <pid> 1s` and see if there are too many fullGarbageCollect

Comment: @MIBMinion does the memory usage increase with each run

Comment: have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748429/java-program-is-getting-slower-after-running-for-a-while?rq=1

Comment: @gismo , yeah ! , even with using GC code sometimes ..

Comment: @MIBMinion then you have a memory leak, look at fields, and variables in bigger loops, and the answer i commented

Comment: @gismo , you commented ? i haven't seen anything useful in the link that u have posted .. shortly, what i have to do ?

Comment: @Gismo , i have tested the project in another PC and it works perfectly, is the problem in my PC ?

Comment: @MIBMinion have alook at the link, there, thez list the possible reasons for the same issue you have

Answer (score 0):

try running your code with the following JVM options -XX:-PrintGCDetails. Analyzing the log will help you get an understanding about the memory usage of your program.